# Adding a .pdf-file using LaTeX not PDFLatex

Tags: graphics, pdfpages, dvips

I want to add a multipage pdf file to my latex document. However, due to some packages that uses eps files I can not use PDFLatex. Instead I use Latex >> ps2pdf.
\includepdf does not work under these conditions.

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Comment: pdflatex handles eps ok, it nowadays converts it on-the-fly to pdf.

Comment: But my package uses eps files and replace a text variable like TMP in them with a number (flexible numbering of chemical structures). Therefore, it needs them as eps during compiling

Comment: Ah. You are using psfrag. You could try the pstool package to get this working with pdflatex. Read the documentation!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use versions of `psfrag` that work with pdftex, but if you want to keep the latex/dvips/ps2pdf workflow you can convert the PDF to a sequence of eps files, for example the standard latex example document `sample2e.pdf` is 3 pages, a command sequence such as

```
pdftops -eps -f 1 -l 1 sample2e.pdf sample2e-1.eps
pdftops -eps -f 2 -l 2 sample2e.pdf sample2e-2.eps
pdftops -eps -f 3 -l 3 sample2e.pdf sample2e-3.eps
```

`pdftops`  is part of the widely available poppler tools

produces three EPS files sample2e-1.eps, sample2e-3.eps, sample2e-3.eps one for each page of the document, that you can then include into latex using graphicx in the usual way.